# Should I remove wardrobe wheels or is there a way to repair this?

Tags: furniture

I bought a long wardrobe with wheels however it seems 2 out of 4 wheels have snapped off.  The pics below show the wheels underneath the wardrobe.  In first pic you can see the black plastic is attached to the wardrobe so wheel still in place in second pic you can see it is broken so no wheel.

1. I'm assuming something like superglue will have no chance and the weight of the wardrobe will just snap it again or is there some way of fixing this?
   Not sure where I could get the replacement part and what I'd need to staple it back in but as its just one piece of furniture dont want to go out and buy an expensive furniture stapler just for this.
2. Might the best thing be to just take all wheels off and use it as such or can you suggest a way to repair/keep the wheels?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised that two sets of wheels are still holding together.  That's an abomination of design if I've ever seen one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways of fixing.

If no need to move it, just take off the wheels.

If needing to move it sometimes, but not often, remove the wheels and place furniture sliders under it.

If wanting the wheels, then buy some wheels, don't need to be the same, and build a platform with wood and screw the new wheels on.

This platform (a piece of plywood) can be glued and screwed to the bottom edges or use short pieces of 2x3 or 2x4 and glue and screw to inside bottom and a piece of wood (plywood like) on top, depends on the height you have to work with.

Comment: I agree that furniture sliders are the way to go. Wheels just don't roll well on carpet and leave divots.  I like the 16 pack of 3 1/2" sliders a the Home Depot.

Comment: Replacing all 4 wheels would be the way to go if staying with wheels. Mounting them to something more solid like plywood or solid wood is definitely better, too. However, mounting that solid wood to the existing chipboard carcass of the wardrobe will take using the proper fasteners and pre-drilling. You can't just drive screws into the edge of that stuff. If it doesn't fall apart when driving screws, it most certainly will the first time it's rolled, especially if it's on carpet.

Comment: The design failure here was not taking into account the weight of the furniture, possibly fully loaded when being move (or not).   Those plastic corners are a joke.  You should build something out of plywood, and figure out how to attach that will bear weight.  Either attach at multiple points, cut a dado, and/or run something vertically to that next edge I see.